# R Missing Data by Variable

Tags: r, missing-data

Is there an efficient method of deriving the total number of missing values for each variable in a data frame using R? I can see how to evaluate each variable, but that seems quite inefficient if the data frame has numerous variables. Thanks.

Comment: what about just using summary() ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
colSums(is.na(df1))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix( sample(c(NA,1:5), 100*20, 
                 replace=TRUE), ncol=20))
```